# Any way to mitigate the disadvantage of code injection through java.eval() method?

Tags: java, security

java.eval()  this was been used for executing JS code generated by the system. Veracode is showing code injection vulnerability.

Comment: Sorry im confused here, java has an eval function? Or did you mean Javascript?

Comment: Why do you think of not having code injection if you directly execute foreign code?

Comment: @DownloadPizza he could mean `ScriptEngine#eval`

Comment: Yes, Java eval method...https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html

Comment: @dan1st Basically it take input from web page based on that, in backend generating appropriate JS function, which further stored in DB. Next time user want to use the same, js function is fetched from db and executed.

Comment: Just try not to use things like eval. This is remote code execution by design.

Comment: Thats i am keeping as the last option as its the core functionality, @dan1st any blacklisting will work ?

Comment: Not really. You would need to block everything except the things you really need but you really should change your design.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS52-J.+Prevent+code+injection

Quoting from above link:
There are mainly 2 compliant solutions:

1. Whitelisting
   The best defense against code injection vulnerabilities is to prevent the inclusion of executable user input in code.
2. Secure Sandbox
   An alternative approach is to create a secure sandbox.

Comment: There are lot off code chunks which need to be added in whitelist bucket.

Comment: Secure sandbox using java security manager, as per what i remember we can have one Security manager instance/jvm . If we provided restricted access to ScriptEngine#Eval, it hampers other follow up code which need those access like file, network etc etc.